# Polymorphism in C++ std::list<T>::iterator

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, polymorphism, virtual, invocation

Ignoring a lot of detail:
Suppose i have an abstract `Card` class containing the function:
    `virtual int getType()=0;`

derived by the also abstract `GreenCard` in which there is a
     `virtual int getType()=0;`
as well.

Then `GreenCard` is derived by non-abstract `Follower` and `Item` where the pure virtual is defined:

```
int getType(){ return 1;}
```

in the Follower class and

```
int getType(){ return 2;}
```

in the Item class.

Later i create (and fill) a list of GreenCard pointers

`list<GreenCard*>* hand;`

...i want to print the hand cards (depending on their types) in a loop:

```
    list<GreenCard *>::iterator it;

    for(it=hand->begin() ; it!=hand->end() ; ++i){
        tp.getCorrectType(*it);
            ...
    }
```

and in this function i get the SegFault in the first line!

```
void getCorrectType(GreenCard* card)
{
    /*SF here->*/  if(card->getType()==2){
        ...
    }
}
```

i am sure that the "card" is properly created and initialized because right in the previous line i write in the gdb: p *card
...and i can see all of its fields (Card, GreenCard and Item related ones-yes it is an 'item') beeing correct!

Edit: ok then heres some more code:

```
class Player{

    list<GreenCard*>*   fateDeck;
    list<GreenCard*>*   hand;
    static const int START_HAND = 4;

    Player(){ 
        fateDeck = new list<GreenCard*> ();
        hand = new list<GreenCard*>();
    }

    void initialize(){
        DeckBuilder db;

        *fateDeck = *(db.createFateDeck() );

        db.deckShuffler(fateDeck);
        initializeHand();
     }

    void initializeHand(){
        for(int counter=0 ; counter<START_HAND ; counter++){
            drawFateCard();
}

    void drawFateCard(){
        hand->push_front(fateDeck->front());
        fateDeck->pop_front();
        cout<<'\n'<<"Drawing from fate deck..."<<'\n'<<endl;
    }

    void Player::printHand(){

        TypeConverter tp;
        list<GreenCard *>::iterator it;

         cout<<"You have " << hand->size()<<" fate cards in hand"<<'\n'
         <<"They are the following:"<<endl;

         for(it=hand->begin() ; it!=hand->end() ; ++it){
             tp.getCorrectType(*it);
             // printing depending on type
         }
    }

    void startingPhase(){
        printHand();
    }
}

class DeckBuilder
{
private:
    list<GreenCard*>* green;

public:
    DeckBuilder();
    list<GreenCard *>* createFateDeck();

    void deckShuffler(list<GreenCard*>* green);
}; 

DeckBuilder :: DeckBuilder()
{  
    green = new list<GreenCard*>();
    srand ( unsigned ( time (NULL) ) );
}

list<GreenCard *>* DeckBuilder :: createFateDeck()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<40;i++)  green->push_back(new Follower());
    return green;
}

void DeckBuilder :: deckShuffler(list<GreenCard*>* green)
{
    vector<GreenCard *> vect;
    list<GreenCard*> ::iterator it;
    for(it = green->begin();it!=green->end();it++)
        vect.push_back((*it));

            random_shuffle ( vect.begin(), vect.end() );

            green->clear();

            vector<GreenCard*>:: iterator it2;
            for(it2 = vect.begin();it2!=vect.end();it2++)
                green->push_back((*it2));
}
```

and eventually in main()

```
Player pl();
pl.initialize();
pl.startingPhase;
```

and segfaults in printHand();

Comment: Can you show the code where you fill the list? And the segmentation fault output?

Comment: Ditto. It looks like the pointers in the list have gone bad. Do you have the option of using smart pointers (e.g. shared_ptr) instead of raw ones? Also, you didn't say what the `tp` in `tp.getCorrectType()` is...

Comment: @dlf 1)sorry, getCorrectType is method of a class TypeConverter and to call it i create an instance called tp. 2) no unfortunately i have never heard of shared pointers before!

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` or if you haven't got c++11 try `std::tr1::shared_ptr`

Comment: @tillaert i could but it's A LOT of code and kinda confusing...why can it help? as i've written the card is filled correctly as well as the the hole list... posting segfault output...

Comment: @user2409839 shared_ptr is very much worth looking into and may or may not be able to solve the problem you're having. But it should also be possible to solve it without them. You say "ignoring a lot of detail" and I understand the motivation, but unfortunately the devil is often in the details, and that appears to be the case here. I can't see anything obviously wrong with the code you've posted.

Comment: @tillaert Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x006f7374 in ?? ()
 ..by the debugger

Comment: You might have already deleted the object the list is pointing to, but you haven't posted the code that fills your list, which could be the source of your problem. The object could already been deleted, which results in a SIGSEV when you access the object lateron.

Comment: before i post the code i make it clear once again that: right before the faulty line (beeing inside getCorrectType) i can access (via gdb) all the fields and their values which are non-trash and as-they-should-be! so i guess the object the pointer points to IS NOT DELETED!

Comment: Maybe; or maybe the memory has been freed and it's just that nothing else has overwritten it yet. I don't know exactly how your debugger behaves in that case.

Comment: @tillaert not that either... right before the getCorrectType invocation i see (via cout<< this time) that the list containing the objects is still intact...

Comment: @user2409839 - So how do you want SO to help you? You're making the claims that nothing you're doing is wrong, but something *is* wrong. We only have one loop you posted, showing valid C++ code, and a function call. That doesn't really help. `Me and my coworker have searched really deep and still cannot justify this segfault, any ideas why this is happening??` That is the wrong conclusion. There is justification for *every* crash. You just haven't found why the crash occurs.

Comment: @user2409839 - One question is why you're using a pointer to `std::list`, and not just a `std::list` object.  By "over-pointerizing" your program, you give more of a chance to have these issues appear.

Comment: Your main code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

I've pieced together the information you've given me. This compiles and runs without segmentation faults (using Visual Studio 2013):

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

class Card
{
public:
    virtual int getType() = 0;
};

class GreenCard : public Card
{
public:
    virtual int getType() = 0;
};

class Follower : public GreenCard
{
public:
    int getType(){ return 1; }
};

class Item : public GreenCard
{
public:
    int getType(){ return 2; }
};

class TypeConverter
{
public:
    void getCorrectType(GreenCard* card)
    {
    if (card->getType() == 1)
        std::cout << "Follower" << std::endl;
        if (card->getType() == 2){
        std::cout << "Item" << std::endl;
    }
}
};

class DeckBuilder
{
private:
    list<GreenCard*>* green;

public:
    DeckBuilder();
    list<GreenCard *>* createFateDeck();

    void deckShuffler(list<GreenCard*>* green);
};

DeckBuilder::DeckBuilder()
{
    green = new list<GreenCard*>();
    srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));
}

list<GreenCard *>* DeckBuilder::createFateDeck()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)  green->push_back(new Follower());
    return green;
}

void DeckBuilder::deckShuffler(list<GreenCard*>* green)
{
    vector<GreenCard *> vect;
    list<GreenCard*> ::iterator it;
    for (it = green->begin(); it != green->end(); it++)
        vect.push_back((*it));

    random_shuffle(vect.begin(), vect.end());

    green->clear();

    vector<GreenCard*>::iterator it2;
    for (it2 = vect.begin(); it2 != vect.end(); it2++)
        green->push_back((*it2));
}

class Player{
    public:
    list<GreenCard*>*   fateDeck;
    list<GreenCard*>*   hand;
    static const int START_HAND = 4;

    Player(){
        fateDeck = new list<GreenCard*>();
        hand = new list<GreenCard*>();
    }

    void initialize(){
        DeckBuilder db;

        *fateDeck = *(db.createFateDeck());

        db.deckShuffler(fateDeck);
        initializeHand();
    }

    void initializeHand(){
        for (int counter = 0; counter < START_HAND; counter++){
            drawFateCard();
        }
    }

    void drawFateCard(){
        hand->push_front(fateDeck->front());
        fateDeck->pop_front();
        cout << '\n' << "Drawing from fate deck..." << '\n' << endl;
    }

    void Player::printHand(){

        TypeConverter tp;
        list<GreenCard *>::iterator it;

        cout << "You have " << hand->size() << " fate cards in hand" << '\n'
            << "They are the following:" << endl;

        for (it = hand->begin(); it != hand->end(); ++it){
            tp.getCorrectType(*it);
            // printing depending on type
        }
    }

    void startingPhase(){
        printHand();
    }


};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Player pl;
    pl.initialize();
    pl.startingPhase();
    return 0;
}
```

Please provide a small, stand-alone example that demonstrates the error.